# NSArray does not update its data second time I try to access it

Tags: iphone

I am making a call to a web service, the results of the web service are in a form of a string, separated by delimiters.the result string is `1|101|Y|103|Y|105|Y|107|Y|109|Y|112|N|114|N|116|Y|`

Now I tokenize the result string, the first token is 1, and based on this value I display the next menu.

If I do an invalid log in the result is `Error`

and now second time if I enter the correct user name and password, the first token has a value of `Error1`.

How am I to get rid of the results obtained in case of invalid log in?
My loginController.m file is

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"return"])
{

    recordResults = FALSE;
    **NSArray *chunks=[soapResults componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];**

    NSLog(soapResult);
    NSLog([chunks objectAtIndex:0]);//Second time on correct login, it displays in console as Error1

    if([[chunks objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {

        Menu *mv2 = [[Menu alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];
        testAppDelegate *appdel=(testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        appdel.soapResult=self.soapResult;
        self.mv1=mv2;
        NSLog(appdel.soapResult);
        [self presentModalViewController:mv1 animated:YES];
        [mv1 release];

    }else {
        //[[chunks objectAtIndex:0] setText:@""];


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Sorry Invalid Login"
                                                     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];


        username_TextField.text=@"";
        password_TextField.text=@"";
            }


}
```

}

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
[username_TextField release];
[password_TextField release];
[chunks release];
[super dealloc];
```

}

Comment: I would suggest that you edit this question down to the code relevant to the `NSArray` you're having trouble with. Further, you should take some time to format your question so that it is easy for others to read. Cutting and pasting does not work. Please respect those who answer you questions and take some time to clean it up before posting.

Comment: Sorry i am new to stackoverflow, and  i myself was wondering how am i to format this message,Now i have done the changes, you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty difficult for me to follow but, let me get this straight:-
The first time you -startElement you create an NSMutableString 'soapResults'. Every time you -foundCharacters you append them onto 'soapResults'. Every time you -endElement you parse the ever growing 'soapResults'?

Do you really want to only create one 'soapResults' and keep adding on to it?

Comment: actually whenever i loogin i send the username and password to the web service, it authenticates my credentials and returns a string value  1|101|Y|103|Y|105|Y|107|Y|109|Y|112|N|114|N|116|Y| in case of successful login. But in case of invalid login it give me Error as a return string.Now for the first time i enter the invalid credentilas, so my first token or value at [chunks objectAtIndex:0] is Error.Now second time when i enter the correct values , the result should be 1|101|.. and the first token at [chunks objectAtIndex:0] should be 1, However it gives me Error1

Comment: so wait. You are saying that [[@"ERROR" componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"] objectAtIndex:0] == @"Error1" ?

Comment: **NSArray *chunks=[soapResults componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];**

        NSLog(soapResult);//Output: 1|101|Y|103|Y|105|Y|107|Y|109|Y|112|N|114|N|116|Y| But 
        NSLog([chunks objectAtIndex:0]); Output: Error1

Comment: wait.. what is 'soapResult' and what is 'soapResults' ?

Comment: sorry it is soapResults and not soapResult.

Comment: so effectively you're stepping through with the debugger and seeing [[@"1|101|Y|103|Y|105|Y|107|Y|109|Y|112|N|114|N|116|Y|" componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"] objectAtIndex:0] == @"Error1" ?